# Tools for analyzing the slow query log of MySql

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a tool that will help me analyze my slow queries log of MySql, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try mysqldumpslow, part of MySQL?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldumpslow.html

Answer (score 0):

I like this Ruby gem: https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer